# java- generate id (combination of string and integer)

Tags: java, sql, string

I am making an application in NetBeans (java). This application has unique id combination of string and integer like `abc/111` or `xyz/253` and the integer part should increase by when a new entry takes place in the database i.e. `abc/112` and `xyz/254`.

The problem is the value of integer part increase until it has reached 10 in a proper way but after that it does not increase and remain same for further entries in database.

I used the following code -

```
try{
    String sql = "SELECT RegNumber FROM Death ORDER BY RegNumber DESC   ";
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

    rs = pst.executeQuery();

    if (rs.next()) {

        String add1 = rs.getString("RegNumber");
        String[] parts= add1.split("/");
        String part1= parts[0];
        String part2= parts[1];
        int a,b;
        a= Integer.parseInt(part2);
        b=a+1;

        jTextField20.setText(""+part1+"/"+b);


        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "done");
    }
   }
```

"*Integer part increase till 10*" means that if I start the first value of id in database like `abc/1` then new id generates automatically for the next entry with the increasing value 1 that is `abc/2` and for next entry it is `abc/3` and so on in **sequential order** like this: `abc/4`, ..., `abc/10`

But when it has reached `abc/10` the new generated id remains same i.e. `abc/10` for every new entry in database. (I am using MS Access 2007 and the `id` is of `text` type). The first id in the database is created by the application itself.

If anyone has another alternative to generate `id`, please tell me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that

```
String sql = "SELECT RegNumber FROM Death ORDER BY RegNumber DESC   ";
```

will sort on descending alphabetic order, and alphabetically speaking

```
"abc/9" > "abc/10"
```

and that's why your program always fetches 9 over and over again...

I think you will have to split up that column for storage, and store the numeric part as an actual number type in the database.  That's probably not as hard as it sounds, you can always sort on 2 fields

```
String sql = "SELECT RegNumber FROM Death ORDER BY RegString DESC, RegNumber DESC   ";
```

You could also consider using a `SERIAL` (autoincrement) datatype for the RegNumber part in certain cases (ie if RegNumber is not reset eg when the string part changes) to simplify your insertion logic further.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, As u advised I can split the RegNumber in two parts but the problem is that This application has the option of "search" and when the full RegNumber entered in the "Search_textfield" then the other fields get the values from database according to the "RegNumber". If I split the RegNumber in two parts how the single textfield i.e. "Search_textfield" will match with the parted RegNumber..............

Comment: you'll have to recombine the field when you want to start the search on it, i don't see any other solution...

Comment: I m not so very good in programming So please tell me How I can combine these firlds

Comment: Actually the code is identical to what you already show here, but reverse (split the content of the textfield and feed these two parts to a query).  If you run into further problems, I'd suggest you post a new question, the SO community will be glad to help you.

Comment: @Durvesh care to share the reason why you unaccepted my answer?

Comment: Sorry for this I m new on Stackoverflow and I was just checking the working of Check signed option. Sorry Once again

Comment: @Durvesh I was mainly worried that you had discovered some issue with the answer - OK then, glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

Your select query is sorting the entries in desc order, which are Varchar type
"SELECT RegNumber FROM Death ORDER BY RegNumber DESC "

Which means after sorting its getting values as
abc/9, abc/8, abc/7, abc/6, abc/5, abc/4, abc/3, abc/2, abc/10, abc/1.

Which means first id is 9 always, which means next value would be 10 always.